# PHP substr after a certain char, a substr + strpos elegant solution?

Tags: php, substr, strpos

let's say I want to return all chars after some needle char `'x'` from:

`$source_str = "Tuex helo babe"`.

Normally I would do this:

```
if( ($x_pos = strpos($source_str, 'x')) !== FALSE )
   $source_str = substr($source_str, $x_pos + 1);
```

**Do you know a better/smarter (more elegant way) to do this?**

Without using regexp that would not make it more elegant and probably also slower.

Unfortunately we can not do:

```
$source_str = substr(source_str, strpos(source_str, 'x') + 1);
```

Because when `'x'` is not found `strpos` returns `FALSE` (and not `-1` like in JS).
`FALSE` would evaluate to zero, and 1st char would be always cut off.

Thanks,

Comment: Use your first approach.

Comment: couldn't you remove the "!== FALSE" and this way it will be a little more compact?

Comment: @Gumbo, I'm afraid you are right. Plz write it down as an answer, and I choose yours, unless something better comes out.

Comment: You could force the FALSE to a 0 with 'intval': $source_str=substr($source_str,intval(strpos($source_str,'x'))+1);

Comment: @patrick: why would I need to force FALSE into 0? FALSE is already converted to zero by PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first approach is fine: Check whether `x` is contained with `strpos` and if so get anything after it with `substr`.

But you could also use [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr):

```
strstr($str, 'x')
```

But as this returns the substring beginning *with* `x`, use `substr` to get the part after `x`:

```
if (($tmp = strstr($str, 'x')) !== false) {
    $str = substr($tmp, 1);
}
```

But this is far more complicated. So use your `strpos` approach instead.

Comment: But strstr return FALSE if needle is not found, not the entire string.

Comment: from PHP 5.3+ strstr() accepts an optional third parameter 'before_needle' which allows you to include or exclude the needle. So no need to use substr anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Regexes would make it a lot more elegant:

```
// helo babe
echo preg_replace('~.*?x~', '', $str);

// Tuex helo babe
echo preg_replace('~.*?y~', '', $str);
```

But you can always try this:

```
// helo babe
echo str_replace(substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'x')) . 'x', '', $str);

// Tuex helo babe
echo str_replace(substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'y')) . 'y', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($source_str, 'x') !== FALSE )
   $source_str = strstr($source_str, 'x');
```

Less elegant, but without `x` in the beginning:

```
if(strpos($source_str, 'x') !== FALSE )
   $source_str = substr(strstr($source_str, 'x'),1);
```

Comment: this will include the 'x' within $source_str though

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, but it's argueable that this is more elegant, and definitely slower "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead." [source: http://it.php.net/strstr]

Comment: I'm confused. `strpos` is to check for substring occurence and it is used in my answer. `strstr` is to return portion of string, only if substring occurs. I find it more elegant because it does'nt need auxiliary variable, there is no misleading assignment in `if()` line and it's shorter. The only flaw of it is what @adam mentioned

Comment: sorry, I probably did not properly explain myself, I think using a strpos+strstr is slower than using a strpos+substr. I did not test for performance (so I'm not sure, but the speed difference might be unnoticable), but beside this, it's still a two line of codes with an if (very similar to code in my question), I was hoping someone could come out with a more concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

I needed just this, and striving to keep it on one line for fun came up with this:

`ltrim(strstr($source_str, $needle = "x") ?: $source_str, $needle);`

The `ternary operator` was adapted in 5.3 to allow this to work.

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

NB. `ltrim` will trim multiple matching characters at the start of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Append a '-' at the end of `$item` so it always returns string before '-' even `$item` doesn't contain '-', because strpos by default returns the *position of first occurrence* of '-'.

```
substr($item,0,strpos($item.'-','-'))
```

Comment: I kinda liked this approach, why it is not good? I think it saves a compute cycle...